# How to pass param to ctor of instance that is created by ObjectFactory

Tags: structuremap

I using StructureMap to create instances of ModuleData

I have many classes that inherit from ModuleData(class A,B,C...) and each of them get Config1 or Config2 in coustructor
In **Registry**(located in file1.cs) I scan all types of ModuleData.

In **Get**(lacated in file2.cs) I get the instance.

I want that when ObjectFactory creates Config1/Config2 while creating instance of ModuleData it will pass "param" to Config1/Config2 constructors.
How I can configure structuremap to do this?

P.S. **Registry** & **Get** methods are located in **different** files!!!
Thank you

```
public class Config1
{
     Config1(string param)
     {
     }
}
public class Config2
{
     Config2(string param)
     {
     }
}
//.....//
public class A : ModuleData
{
    A(Config1 c)
   {
   }
}
public class B : ModuleData
{
    A(Config2 c)
   {
   }
}
//....//
//located in file1.cs
public Registry()
{
     Scan(x =>
     {
          x.TheCallingAssembly();
          x.AddAllTypesOf<ModuleData>();
     });            
     ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
     {
             x.For<Config1>().Use<Config1>();
             x.For<Config2>().Use<Config2>();
     });
}    
//....//
//located in file2.cs
public ModuleData Get(object o)
{
    var module = o as PageModule;
    var t = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1},{2}", Settings.Namespace, module.Name, Settings.Assembly));
    return ObjectFactory.With("param").EqualTo(module.Parameters).GetInstance(t) as ModuleData;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a good way to do what you want, I think its a bit of a design problem...  I think you   would have to explain a bit more about why you need to do this for me to help you.

What is a page module?  Why is your config objects dependent on it?

Based on your comment, I think what you need is a factory object that creates ModuleData objects for you.  Since they are objects it does not make much sense to get them from the container.  Think about using a data access technology like Entity Framework, it would not make sense to get those objects from the container.  From what I can tell, this is a similar case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Config object is deserializer. It receives string, deserialize it and fill itself. And ModuleData objects(A,B...) use this config objects to do job. So, instead the ModuleData objects will receive string, create Config object and fill it, I want them(ModuleData objects) already to receive filled Config Objects. PageModule is class that is used for building type of object to be instantiated by ObjectFactory.